# How to control the order of execution of two thread accessing the same shared data

Tags: c++, multithreading

in my example thread 1 and 2 write to the same shared resource `x`.
and the main thread will read the value.
I want to have the result `24` i.e. thread2 then thread1.

how can I control that ? I tried to define thread 2 before 1 and print the result after `join` the two threads and the result was `24` but this result is not guaranteed since the threads work in parallel

```
    int x = 10;

    void mainThread1(){

        x *= 2; 

    }

    void mainThread2(){
        x += 2;

    }

    int main() {

        std::thread th1(mainThread1);
        std::thread th2(mainThread2);

        std::cout << x << std::endl; // random print 20 or 22

        th1.join();
        th2.join();
 }
```

Comment: The example is simplified so much that it's hard to understand what you're trying to do. The obvious answer is: don't use threads, or join `th2` before starting `th1`, but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Practically you don't have control, its all up to the thread scheduling by the  OS.

Comment: You need a resource that you share between the threads so that Thread2 waits for a flag that Thread1 will set when finished.

Comment: if I can't what is the role of `critical section` then ? I can read here [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section)  "variable x is protected by a critical section. First, B gets the access to the section. Once B finishes writing the value, A gets the access to the critical section, and variable x can be read."

Comment: A critical section is used to force mutual exclusion (only one thread can be in the critical section at any one time).  It does *not* force any particular sequencing of threads.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you are looking for something other than the trivial answer here: join the first thread before starting the second one. You are showing a simplified example to illustrate a more general situation.

> this result is not guaranteed since the threads work in parallel

This is correct. Issues related to relative sequences of operations between multiple threads, and when the effects of one execution thread are "visible" in another execution thread fall into a rather broad, complicated, and extensive C++ domain called "synchronization".

Inter-thread synchronization employs mutexes, condition variables, and atomics. Just like every other large C++ topic it is impractical to describe everything that needs to be described about synchronization in a brief answer on Stackoverflow, here. That would take pages. Therefore, I'll just provide a capsule summary of how this simple use case would handle synchronization, and refer you for all further gory details to your favorite C++ textbook or reference material, for more information. But the basic outline of how to do this here is:

1. Define a mutex, a condition variable, and a `bool` flag, in addition to `x`.
2. The first execution thread locks the mutex, updates `x`, sets the `bool` flag, and notifies the condition variable, then releases the mutex.
3. The second execution thread locks the mutex, then `wait_for` the condition variable, with the condition being `flag == true`.
4. The second execution thread updates `x`, and releases the mutex.

This is the classical solution that guarantees the order of execution, between the two execution threads, that you are looking for. The above answers how to guarantee that the results of

> thread2 then thread1

are produced in the shown code.

Comment: 5. `wait()` directly on an atomic variable.

Comment: does the passage through a mutex necissary ?? . I see that if I can block thread 1 so that it waits for the flag is sufficient without having to go through a mutex.

Comment: Yes, it is required. Mutexes are not just for locking, but also for proper inter-thread sequencing. Without proper sequencing any changes made by one execution thread are not guaranteed to be visible in any other execution thread. Just because one thread changes a variable does not mean that this change will be visible in another execution thread without what's called "sequencing". C++ is complicated.

Comment: yes I understand what do u mean. if one thread made a change in a shared data (write) other threads may read the previous shared data value as they can read the new value. but in my case I have a bool flag ! `mainThread1` will not continue until he revceived the true flag so I can wait in thread 1 without locking because I'm sure that thread 2 will be executed before thread 1. then when flag is true the shared data x inside thread 1 will be the new one. I don't know if in C++ I can wait without locking. to resume in my case sequencing is guaranteed through the flag.

Comment: It doesn't matter if something is a `bool` flag, or a large structure. Proper sequencing, using mutexes, is required. Can you explain how you believe that "sequencing is guaranteed"? Just because the thread sets a `bool` variable to some value, by itself, gives you absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, that the `bool` variable's new value is visible to any other execution thread, until this is correctly sequenced. C++ just doesn't work this way. The word "sequencing" here is a specific term, referencing a core C++ fundamental concept, and not just some English word with a particular meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global `condition_variable` so that:

- The thread to be executed in second place waits for it.
- The thread to be executed in first place does its job and sets it.

Notice threads can be woken up from a wait on a condition variable due to [spurious wakeups](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) so you should provide an extra mechanism, e.g. a bool, to tell a `notify` actually happened.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/3zTrEMj1T)

```cpp
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

int x{10};
bool ready{false};
std::mutex m{};
std::condition_variable cv{};

void mainThread1() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk{m};
    cv.wait(lk, []{ return ready; });
    x *= 2; 
}

void mainThread2() {
    x += 2;
    ready = true;
    cv.notify_one();
}

int main() {
    std::thread th1(mainThread1);
    std::thread th2(mainThread2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    std::cout << x << "\n";  // prints 24
}
```

A simpler solution would come of using a `binary_semaphore`. The idea is the same: thread 1 waits for a signal coming from thread 2, but the code is quite more high level and leaner.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/nWe4db7Yj)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <semaphore>
#include <thread>

int x{10};
std::binary_semaphore bs{0};

void mainThread1() {
    bs.acquire();
    x *= 2; 
}

void mainThread2() {
    x += 2;
    bs.release();
}

int main() {
    std::thread th1(mainThread1);
    std::thread th2(mainThread2);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

    std::cout << x << "\n";  // prints 24
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of going through a mutex in `mainThread1` , did you just use it to pass it in `wait` ? why am I locking in `mainThread1` and am sure it cannot modify the shared resource before receiving the flag `ready` ?

Comment: 1) `mainThread1` locks waiting for a condition variable; condition variables in C++ use a lock; and locks use a mutex. 2) Threads waiting on a condition variable can be woken up for circumstances (spurious wakeups) other than another thread doing a notify on that condition variable; in order to be sure you are woken up for another thread doing a notify on that condition, you do an extra check, e.g. a bool value.

Comment: @DoctorX I've edited my answer adding a simpler solution based on a counting semaphore.